# Variables not changed when in paintComponent() method

Tags: java, swing, methods, null, graphics2d

Lets say I make a simple graphical application. It has two classes, the main class and a second class called "panel" that extends JPanel.
The main class is just a JFrame that contains the JPanel. Here are its contents:

```
public static Panel panel = new Panel();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JPanel p = new Panel();
    JFrame fr = new JFrame();
    fr.setSize(600, 600);
    fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    fr.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    fr.setVisible(true);
    fr.add(p);
    while (true) {
        fr.repaint();
        if (panel.test) panel.g2d.drawRect(30, 30, 40, 40);
    }
}
```

The second class uses Graphics2D to create the contents of the JPanel. It also has variables that are changed within the paintComponent() method. Here are its contents:

```
Graphics2D g2d;
boolean test = false;

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    test = true;
    g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2d.drawRect(10, 10, 20, 20);
}
```

However, here's the problem: neither `test` nor `g2g` appear to change after the paintComponent() method has executed. The code in the while loop of the main method never ends up drawing a rectangle though the paintComponent() method draws its rectangle fine. In the main method, `test` and `g2g` appear to always be `false` and `null` respectively. What am I missing here? Is there anyway to use the graphics2D outside the paintComponent() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of that `while (true)` block, it's not needed and it's harmful as it risks stomping on your GUI thread. Instead add your JPanel ***before*** calling `setVisible(true)` on your JFrame.

Also, creating a Graphics2D field and trying to draw with it outside of paintComponent is inviting a NullPointerException. Understand that you don't have full control over Swing Graphics and should not try to extract a Graphics object or do drawing that way. You will  want to read the Swing Graphics tutorial to learn how to properly draw with Swing components.

- [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html): introductory tutorial to Swing graphics
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html): advanced tutorial on Swing graphics

So to answer,

> Is there anyway to use the graphics2D outside the paintComponent() method?

No. You can get around this by drawing with a BufferedImage's Graphics object, but then you still need to draw the BufferedImage to your JPanel or JComponent's paintComponent method.

Comment: Did the said changes but the problem persists

Comment: @SuperNew: If you make changes to your code, then post your new code as an edit to your original question. Don't get rid of your original code, but add the new code below it. Show more of your code as well. Also don't name any class "Panel" as that clashes with a core Java class name. Also, have you read the tutorials yet?

Answer (score 0):

Try to ovveride this method too with the same code:

```
            @Override
            public void paintComponents(Graphics grphcs)
            {
                super.paintComponents(grphcs);
                //add code here
            }
```

And also i recomand not to use JPanel pointer to awt Panel variable . 
 So change :

```
       `JPanel p = new Panel();  to `JPanel p = new JPanel();`
```